# PHP - DatePeroid no 2015 year in list

Tags: php, date

i'm trying to get list of weeks between two years

```
$p = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('2014-12-01'), 
    new DateInterval('P1W'), 
    new DateTime('2015-01-05')
);
foreach ($p as $w) {
    echo $w->format('Y-W') , PHP_EOL;
}
```

But it shows only 2014 and instead of `2015-01` it shows `2014-01`
What's wrong with this code?

Output looks like this:

```
2014-49
2014-50
2014-51
2014-52
2014-01
```

Comment: Well 29th of December is part of the first week of 2015, but it's still a day from 2014. And that's why its shown like 2014-01.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `W` for weeks in dates you must use `o` for years. Example `echo $w->format('o-W')`.
Resource [php date manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).